# UIImage is not showing after selecting image from gallery or camera

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to select image from camera or gallery and showing the selected image to the screen in my image view. But it's not showing.

```
  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                               didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
            fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
        }

        imageview.image = selectedImage

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

What am I missing?

[image]

In my case the breakpoint function is not at all invoking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your breakpoint function is not at invoking then I think you have not set the imagePicker delegate in viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     imagePicker.delegate = self   
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue before and resolved it by setting image with delay like showed below:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
    self.imageview.image = selectedImage
})
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` added to your class and have set your `UIImagePickerController` instance delegate:

```
class PickerViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    var pickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerController.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Also, it's better to dismiss the `picker` parameter sent to this delegate:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    ...

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This is not right. You’re suggesting delegate method with old parameters `[String:Any]`. So then he just creates a new a method

Comment: @RobertDresler You're right. However the problem was with setting the delegate. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I’m sorry, you suggested good thing `picker.dismiss`, I just didn’t notice it because you didn’t write that you’re doing this change

Comment: @RobertDresler It seems he had no problem using `dismiss` so it was unnecessary anyways. Thank you though.

Comment: even if it looks like that, this was actually good suggestion which has to be in the code, so put it back ;)

Comment: @RobertDresler It's back to the answer ;-)